# Apache to IIS web.config?

Tags: caching, iis, server, web-config

I am used to working with Apache or NGINX, but a new client has its website on a Microsoft IIS server that makes use of web.config where he would like to add caching.

I normally use the following setup:

```
### Begin Caching Performance ###
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we’re sending far-future expires, we don’t need ETags for static content.
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Pragma
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header unset Pragma
            Header append Cache-Control "public"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Gzip Compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            # Don’t compress images and other uncompressible content
            SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
            \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                "application/javascript" \
                                "application/json" \
                                "application/ld+json" \
                                "application/manifest+json" \
                                "application/rdf+xml" \
                                "application/rss+xml" \
                                "application/schema+json" \
                                "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                "application/x-javascript" \
                                "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                "application/xml" \
                                "font/eot" \
                                "font/opentype" \
                                "image/bmp" \
                                "image/svg+xml" \
                                "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                "image/x-icon" \
                                "text/cache-manifest" \
                                "text/css" \
                                "text/html" \
                                "text/javascript" \
                                "text/plain" \
                                "text/vcard" \
                                "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                "text/vtt" \
                                "text/x-component" \
                                "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                "text/xml"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/html .html_gzip
    AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

# Expires headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                  "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest               "access plus 0 seconds"

# CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                          "access plus 1 year"

# Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                  "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                      "access plus 1 week"

# HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                  "access plus 1 month"

# HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                         "access plus 0 seconds"

# JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript            "access plus 1 year"

# Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media
    ExpiresByType image/gif                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                        "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                        "access plus 1 month"

# Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml              "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                "access plus 1 hour"

# Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject     "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                     "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                     "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # mod_headers
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Webfont access
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(tt[cf]|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
### End Caching Performance ###
```

So this or at least some parts to GZIP and Expiration Headers I would like to add to this website to make it more performant. Does anyone know how I would be able to convert or at least point me in the right direction to convert the above performance and caching code to Microsoft IIS's web.config?

Thanks in advance for more information!

Comment: IIS was designed with a different mindset, so except digging into its configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/ there is no much to be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have configured the web.config like this, the reason I am doing it directly via the web.config is that the client does not have access to the IIS control panel nor does the host company want to provide it.

This is the code I eventually came up with:

```
<!-- General Optimisation-->
<directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
<!-- Security Headers -->
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Security-By" value="Sandhills Studio"/>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="img-src 'self' https: data: blob:; font-src 'self' https: data:;"/>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
    <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer-when-downgrade"/>
    <add name="Expect-CT" value="max-age=86400,enforce"/>
    <add name="Feature-Policy" value="fullscreen *;camera 'none';microphone 'none'"/>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"/>
    <!--Remove Headers-->
    <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By-Plesk"/>
    <remove name="Pragma"/>
    <remove name="ETag"/>
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<!-- GZip static file content -->
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="512">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="10"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/ld+json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/manifest+json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/rdf+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/schema+json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/vnd.geo+json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="font/eot" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="font/opentype" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="image/bmp" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="image/x-icon" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
<!-- Clinet Cache Control -->
<staticContent>
     <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" setEtag="false"/>
    <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
    <remove fileExtension=".air"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".css"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".rss"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".html"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".xml"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <!-- HTML5 Audio/Video mime types-->
    <remove fileExtension=".mp3"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ogg"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ogv"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".webm"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
    <!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
    <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".svgz"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
    <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ttc"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".less"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".crx"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".xpi"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".safariextz"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
    <!-- Flash Video mime types-->
    <remove fileExtension=".flv"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".f4v"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <!-- Assorted types -->
    <remove fileExtension=".ico"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".webp"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".htc"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".vcf"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".torrent"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".cur"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".webapp"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8"/>
</staticContent>
```

Sadly SVG isn't being GZipped, even though listed is on a lower level that this has to be included as it seems IIS doesn't recognise this mime type by default.

If anyone has any suggestions, feel free to let me know!